# Is A∩B has Maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Consider $A=(0,1)∪\{2\}$ and $B=(0,1)∪\{3\}$. Both sets have maxima, $2$ and $3$ respectively. But $A∩B=(0,1)$ which has no maximum.

How can we say that $A∩B=(0,1)$ does not have any maximum. Wouldn't it be $1$ ?

Comment: $1$ is the supremum, the lowest upper bound. But it is not the maximum since it doesn't belong to the set in question.

Comment: No. 1 is here our supremum. Pls have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum

Comment: Protip: to show the `{` and `}` as in $\{2\}$ or $\{3\}$, you must add \, like  \{ 2 \} . I've fixed it for you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1$ is not a max, since the interval $(0,1)$ is open, this means, in particular that $1$ is not in the set. This set has no max, but it has an upper bound.

Comment: and a lower bound of course.

Comment: In fact we can go further and say that it has a *least* upper bound and a *greatest* lower bound.

Comment: If it has a Closed interval , then would it have maximum ?

Comment: Yes. The supremum, if it belongs to the set, then it is the *maximum*.